# Recommended time for global entry interview on arrival?

Tags: global-entry

Is there a minimum time that should be planned to allow a global entry interview on arrival?  I'm arriving in IAH, but I have a domestic connection 1h50m after scheduled arrival time that goes to my final destination.  I can't find any real guidance as to what is recommended.  It's also a little hard for me to get out to the airport for an interview in general, so I'm also a little leery of paying the $100 and not being able to complete the process for several months.

Comment: When is your trip? You can't do enrollment on arrival until you're conditionally approved, and it can take quite a while to get to that point these days, though it seems to vary person-to-person. If you're counting on doing the interview on arrival after you arrive in IAH and haven't applied yet, that could be an issue unless your trip is far enough in the future.

Comment: @ZachLipton for purposes of this question, lets pretend I'm already conditionally approved and my (scheduled) interview is in 4 months.  I realize there are other steps that need to be passed before one is eligible to do interview on arrival, but I'm just looking for one particular point about which I can't seem to find almost any information about...

Comment: Perfect. I just didn't want you to spend the $100 counting on the timing to work if you weren't aware of the wait.

Comment: @ZachLipton for those playing the home game, my time from payment to conditional approval was approximately 2 business hours.  I will update this question next month when I return from the trip.

Comment: Wow. Mine just took months, and that was a renewal. Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual data point. Off the jet bridge at 2:20, in line for global entry interview at 2:27, finished with interview at 2:40. There was one person in the middle of their interview when I arrived at the special interview booth, which for my particular arrival I guess was on the other “side” of the arrivals hall. I guess every airport has a different layout. This is probably highly variable, but it probably helps to hustle off the plane, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When I arrived in New York JFK and wanted to do the interview on arrival, the officer told me the wait time would be around 1 hour, until another officer would be available who could do the interview. This was in February 2019, right after the end of the shutdown. So with barely 2 hours connection time, I would ask them how long it would take, but I would prepare for not being able to complete the interview in such a time window.

But another point that sounds strange to me: usually the EoA counters are in the section where international flights arrive. So you need to complete the regular immigration process anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily IAH is on of the airports that have Global Entry On Arrival (https://www.fly2houston.com/newsroom/articles/cbp-launches-global-entry-enrollment-arrival/ ) You would do your immigration checkin and global entry interview at the same time. No appointment is needed.

Just find the signs for Global Entry Upon Arrival near the manned immigration stations.

Otherwise, I’ve found that at the regular Global Entry Offices if you have a tight schedule, you can tell the officer when you checkin and they try their best to accommodate you.